# How do you add a site to the Internet Explorer Trusted Zone through GPO in server 2003?

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

How do you add a site to the Internet Explorer Trusted Zones through GPO in server 2003?

If you do push a site through a GPO does it erase other Trusted Sites that may have been entered on the end users computer?

Thank You,
Keith

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*This does clear all the users prevoiusly added sites to **ALL** their securitys lists.*

1. Open Group Policy Manager
2. Create New GPO and Link it.
3. Edit GPO.
4. Browse to User Config -> Admin Temp -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel -> Security Page
5. Open "Site to Zone Assignment List"
6. Enable it
7. Click Show and add your site name and the value 2 for the Trusted Zones list

Keith

Answer (score 1):

To set a trusted site, in Group Policy editor: 
Navigate to
User Config\Admin Templates\Windows Components\Internet Control Panel\Security Page\

Policy: Site to Zone Assignment List

Any site you add to the list with a value to 2, will be in the trusted sites zone.

I think it will merge with existing sites if you have not locked down the zone

see [Internet Explorer security zones registry entries for advanced users](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=182569)

and [Group Policy and Internet Explorer 8](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx)

Comment: Thank you... I was typing my answer and didnt see yours.